# Two objects need each other

Tags: c#

Basically I have 3 classes: `Game`, `Level` and `Player` (which is a `GameObject`). Stripped to the bare minimum it looks something like this:

```
class Game
{
    private Level[] levels;
    private Player player;

    public Game()
    {
        levels = new []{new Level(player)};
        player = new Player(levels[0]);
    }
}

class Level
{
    private List<GameObject> gameObjects;

    public Level(Player player)
    {
        gameObjects.Add(player);
    }

    public void DoSomething() {}
}

class Player : GameObject
{
    private Level level;

    public Player(Level level)
    {
        this.level = level;
        level.DoSomething();
    }
}

abstract class GameObject {}
```

Is it possible to make this work somehow? `player` *must* be created inside `Game`.

Comment: Well get them together already!

Comment: What is your question? "Getting it to work" can mean many different things? When would you consider your code to be working?

Comment: @stakx My goal is to create `Level`s with the same `Player` instance and being able to call `level.DoSomething()` from `Player`.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your design. There is no "has-a" relation between player and level, in neither direction (or at least not in both). Or if you think there is, explain why tou think so.

As you found out, using your current design you can't instantiate the one without the other, creating a circular dependency. Of course, to "just make it work" you can create a property or setter method:

```
pubic class Player
{
    private Level _level;

    public Level Level 
    { 
        get { return _level; }
        set { _level = value; }
    }

    // Or auto-implemented property
    public Level Level { get; set; }

    public Player()
    {        
    }
}
```

(Or the same, but then for the Level).

Now you can instantiate a player without requiring a level:

```
var player = new Player();
var level = new Level(player);
player.Level = level;
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, you can't instantiate one object without already having the other. If you want to keep the design you have now a solution would be to have a `Game` reference in each other class, like this:

```
class Level
{
    private Game game;

    public Level(Game game)
    {
        this.game = game;
    }
}

class Player
{
    private Game game;

    public Player(Game game)
    {
        this.game = game;
    }
}
```

You would construct them inside the Game class like this:

```
levels = { new Level(this) } // (this refers to the instance of Game)
player = new Player(this);
```

since the constructors accept an instance of `Game`

Then to access the levels or player object, you would do this inside `Level` or `Player`:

```
this.game.levels
```

or

```
this.game.player
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, next time add `Unity` tag to your question.
As it is now it is not going to work because currently `Player` class requires instance of `Level` class (in constructor) and `Level` class requires instance of `Player` class - this makes circular dependence and neither object can be instantiated. So first of all we should break it by removing `Player` to `Level` aggregation. Because of condition that we have (`Player` must be instantiated only inside `Game` class) we should mark it as `abstract` :

```
abstract class AbstractPlayer : GameObject
{
    public Level level { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can modify `Game` class with new logic and add nested concrete `Player` class that inherits from `AbstractPlayer` :

```
class Game
{
    private List<Level> levels;
    private Player player;

    public Game()
    {
        player = new Player();
        Levels.Add(player);
    }

    // uncomment this method if you need it
    //public Player CreatePlayer()
    //{
    //    return new Player();
    //}

    private class Player : AbstractPlayer
    {
        public Player()
        {
        }            
    }
}

class Level
{
    private List<GameObject> gameObjects;

    public Level(Player player)
    {
        gameObjects.Add(player);
        player.Level = this;
    }

    public void DoSomething() {}
}
```

Comment: If `Player` is a class, it will be passed by reference by default